# Openlayer 3 Vector KML style no longer work?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers 3 since a short time. I've finished an application include of map with OpenLayers 3 ten days ago. But today I checked the application that, styles no longer work on `KML`. Does anyone have any idea?

```
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.KML(({
            url: '#',
            projection: 'EPSG:900913'
        }))
         , style: [new ol.style.Style({
             stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 10 })
         })]
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you compare this version with the one you had 10 days ago?

Comment: I could not find a cdn file that can compare. :(

Comment: It is on github. Pull and set the head back ten days.

Comment: Yeah, the styles coding has changed! :\

Comment: Is it a bug, or just a change in the way it is done?

Comment: it is probably no bug just a change, but the change's side effects are a little ominous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there’s been a change in the library: [1] now feature styles has precedence over layer style.
To make your code works, tell your format not to extract styles from the KML like in [2]:

```
source: new ol.source.KML(({
    extractStyles: false,
    url: '#',
    projection: 'EPSG:900913'
}))
```

- 1: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/2394
- 2: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/2477